# Applications of moduli of curves theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, applications, moduli-spaces

Are there some applications of moduli of curves theory? I was wondering if moduli of curves theory is used (or could be used) for doing research in applied mathematics.

I am doing my PhD in algebraic geometry (in particular, moduli of curves) and I would like to focus also on some applications, but I don't know if they exists and I can't find anything on the web. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what "moduli of curves theory" is,  but if I'm not mistaken, there are some pretty amazing applications of the moduli stack of elliptic curves in physics.